# Remove leading 0 from time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to remove the leading zeros from time. I want my time format to be hh:mm:ss without leading 0.
For example: 011:50:35 should just be 11:50:35

Any idea how I can achieve this please.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample data - see image]

Comment: What if there are **2** leading zeros ??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the custom number format of those cells is  `[hhh]:mm:ss`

If that is the case you can change it to:

`[h]:mm:ss`  (no leading zeros)

or

`[hh]:mm:ss`  (one leading zero for hours `0-9` only.

Answer (score 0):

How about the leading number "1"?

I made a brief sample as following. Befor I enter the data, I set the cell format as **Text**.

[image]

I use formula `=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="0",MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-1),A1)` to remove the leading 0, keep the data if leading number is not 0.